# Minecraft Lags Extremely on MacBook Air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an 2010 MacBook Air with Intel Core Duo, 2 GB RAM. I know that macs, specifically MacBook Airs, aren't gaming computers. But this is my only option to play Minecraft on. When I play Minecraft, especially on servers (which is frustrating in PVP fights), the game lags insanely. I have all video options turned off or set to fast, but the game still lags. Any help?

Comment: If it's happening on servers, what is your internet connection speed? And can/does the laptop have a wired connection to the router?

Comment: I use Wi-Fi. On other computers Minecraft works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OptiFine. It helps. It uses all cores of the processor so you will have a little bit improvement. [Here's it.](http://optifine.net/downloads) And the best thing is that you just need java. It's multiplatform. Also check out [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7YUR9NHSfA).

Comment: I'll try it. Sounds good!

Answer (score 3):

Googling "Minecraft minimum requirement", it suggests an **NVidia GeForce 9600 GT**.

Apple support shows a 2010 Macbook Air has a **NVidia GeForce 320M**.

https://support.apple.com/kb/sp618?locale=en_US

Here are the comparison between the two on GPUBoss:

[image]

Your graphics card is basically half the capability of the minimum requirements.  It is expected to be slow.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Also Minecraft needs kinda a lot of RAM. When 1GB is default settings, it is good to use at least 2GB of RAM. The problem is that this MacBook does not have that much. Even 1GB usage is too heavy for it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to play Minecraft on beast of a 2008 MacBook Pro with 8 GB of RAM, and all extra graphics settings off, and it was still a bit laggy. Playing on servers with many other players (and block updates, etc.) was worse.

A 2010 MacBook Air with those specs is a significantly less capable computer than my former beast of a Mac laptop. You're simply giving Minecraft too little computing power to run any better than you are already seeing.

Unfortunately, wishing can't make a computer more powerful than it is.

Comment: It could also be the server and connection in general are playing a role in this users experience.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I sometimes forget I may be speaking with or to someone from outside my local area and unaccustomed to certain colloquialisms. I'll explain -  when I wrote "playing a role" my full intention was to imply  a fraction of the greater whole which exacerbates or otherwise facilitates additional problem to the stated or primary concern; an addendum to the primary cause. I get this user is already operating in a sub-optimal environment as he or she made this obvious in several instances. I'll be more careful to word my comments so they're more easily understood.

Comment: @ShawnGordon I think I may have just read your comment too quickly and missed the “also” that emphasised that it was saying servers might be exacerbating the problem. My fault there! Yes, you're right, the servers could very well be contributing to an already poor performance situation.

Comment: Well I guess I have too buy a new computer, the Mac IS getting old. Or I'll just have too live with it...